# Generate insert statement using a stored procedure for all tables in a database

Tags: oracle

Using a a stored procedure I want to generate insert scripts for all the tables available in database and the table name and the columns must be passed as a parameter, how to do this?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you tried something? If so, Please post the same.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an unsolved problem in Oracle as far as I know.  There are plenty of IDEs that can be used to generate INSERT scripts, such as SQLcl, SQL Developer, TOAD, etc.  But there is not a pure PL/SQL solution to create a script like that.  It's one of those problems that sounds easy at first, and people always say "why not make it yourself?"  Turns out it's surprisingly difficult to do well.